# process shared memory not sharing (c, linux)

Tags: c, memory, process, shared

I need to make a shared memory to my process communicate. I'm doing this:

```
int **matriz_result;
int segment_id;
segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (sizeof(int) * linhas_mat1 * colunas_mat2) , S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
matriz_result = (int **) shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);
```

After this I use fork to make more processes. I tested and each process is writing in `matriz_resul`, but each one has its own area. If I print what's on that area, each process print something different. The memory is not sharing. every example I have found on internet is like this. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not yet sure of the cause, but you really should not be using the legacy sysv ipc functions unless you absolutely have to (e.g. to meet the requirements of some existing API like the XSHM extension). Use POSIX shared memory (`shm_open`) or simply `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
segment_id = mmap(NULL,(sizeof(int) * linhas_mat1 * colunas_mat2),PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED,-1,0 );
```

Comment: the association `matriz_result = (int **) shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);` is still the same using mmap? and the read and write from in this shared memory? and this is from pure C language (not C++)?